# Crystal Report Not Working, Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am working on Visual Studio 2013, platform Windows 8, and crystal report V13, but I am facing two major problems.

Number one is I am not getting designer for report. Whenever I double click on report to open it I am getting following error message.

[image]

2. Second is when application is running I get run time error as in image below:

[image]

Comment: did you install Crystal for Visual Studio?  you have to install this package separately

Comment: Yes I have Installed Crystal Report 13.0.12 which was recommended for VS2013

Comment: well i had to specifically install the Developer version as well from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: I have installed the same Sir, nothing changes

Comment: if you look at `HELP` -> `About Microsoft Visual Studio` do you see Crystal Reports for .NET Framework listed?

Answer (score 0):

We did a lot of reading from the wiki and the KBA and we found by trial and error that this change below added to the app.config works but the KBA really doesn't say why: